# I want when I send the message the alert shows up

Tags: php, mysql, cakephp, xampp

I have here some alert I want to show up when I send the message the problem when I click refresh the alert still show up I want this alert when I click on refresh to disappear

```
<?php 
if(isset($error_message) >0){
    $message = "Grazie per averci contattato. Ci metteremo in contatto con voi molto presto.";
    echo "<script type='text/javascript'>alert('$message');</script>";
}
?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the if statement from

`if(isset($error_message) >0)`

to

```
 if(isset($error_message))
```

Let me know if it works